# Google vision coordinates not accurately returned

Tags: google-cloud-vision

## Summary:

The image shown here https://storage.googleapis.com/visionbucketext/covidvaccine_filled_210421_153054.pdf.png is sent to Cloud vision api's "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION" feature and it is expected the coordinates of the Word "Garvin" in the image should be returned at the coordinates

> "description": "Garvin",
> "boundingPoly": {
> "vertices": [
> {
> "x": 99,
> "y": 308
> },
> ......
> {
> "x":254,
> "y":359
> }
> ]
> }

but it returns

> {
> "description": "Garvin",
> "boundingPoly": {
> "vertices": [
> {
> "x": 154,
> "y": 299
> },
> {
> "x": 276,
> "y": 296
> },
> {
> "x": 278,
> "y": 354
> },
> {
> "x": 156,
> "y": 357
> }
> ]
> }

## Steps Tried:

I tried using auto detection mode and wrong results resulted. Since the document was in English I tried passing the english language hint and it didn't change that coordinate of that element.

## steps to simulate:

YOu could simulate this on the Google Vision API (https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/handwriting) using the request body https://storage.googleapis.com/visionbucketext/CloudVisonREquest.json through Google Vision console .Could you please let me know what other options could be tried to make sure the coordinates returned are accurate?